# How to avoid destroying shared_ptr in inappropriate thread context?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr

This is a relatively simple program reproducing the problem in my application:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/noncopyable.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class worker : boost::noncopyable {
public:
    explicit worker(boost::asio::io_service& io);
    ~worker();
    void just_do_it(const std::function<void()>& when_done);

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& io_;
    boost::asio::io_service worker_io_;
    boost::thread thread_;
};

worker::worker(boost::asio::io_service& io)
: io_(io)
{
    thread_ = boost::thread([this] {
        boost::asio::io_service::work my_work(worker_io_);
        worker_io_.run();
    });
}

worker::~worker()
{
    worker_io_.stop();
    std::clog << "join...\n";
    thread_.join();
}

void worker::just_do_it(const std::function<void()>& when_done)
{
    worker_io_.post([this, when_done] {
        io_.post(when_done);
        boost::asio::steady_timer(worker_io_, std::chrono::seconds(1)).wait();
    });
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io, std::chrono::seconds(5));
    timer.async_wait(std::bind([] { std::clog << "terminating...\n"; }));
    {
        auto my_worker = std::make_shared<worker>(io);
        my_worker->just_do_it([my_worker] {
            std::clog << "did it\n";
            my_worker->just_do_it([my_worker] {
                std::clog << "did it second time\n";
                // now my_worker is not needed and we allow it to die
            });
        });
    }
    io.run();
}
```

When I run it on Linux machine I see:

```
did it
did it second time
join...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::thread_resource_error> >'
  what():  boost thread: trying joining itself: Resource deadlock avoided
Aborted
```

It crashes because of shared_ptr calls worker destructor in worker`s thread. I can fix it this way:

```
std::shared_ptr<worker> holder;
{
    holder = std::make_shared<worker>(io);
    holder->just_do_it([&holder] {
        std::clog << "did it\n";
        holder->just_do_it([&holder] {
            std::clog << "did it second time\n";
            // now worker is not needed and we destroy it
            holder.reset();
        });
    });
}
```

But it is a manual object lifetime management. It is not too much better than using new and delete. Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: You want to join the thread later anyway, right? So you need a handle to the thread outside of it.

Comment: The thread can use worker class member variables so I need to stop it before worker destruction.

Comment: Your solution is not less automatic than your problematic code, you simply changed when the pointer gets destroyed (and is still better than manual `new`/`delete` regarding exceptions for example); you can come up with another solution but the one you provide seems to be the easiest one IMO.

Comment: It becomes not so simple if I call two holder->just_do_it() simultaneously. It results in manual ref-counting.

Comment: Why do you call `reset()`? Your pointer will get destroyed when you leave the scope where `holder` is instantiated, no need to explicitely release the pointer or have I missed something?

Comment: I tried to create a simple example to show my problem. My real application is a daemon which creates workers for handling requests and I do not want that these workers with threads inside exist indefinitely. Imagine that main() logic in {} is not in main() but in some class member and holder is a member of this class also.

Comment: I have found with that this trick is to wrap `servers` in `managers`. Let the `manager` start and stop servers and control their lifetimes. If the code involves callbacks (as opposed to the asio-handler paradigm) then enable_shared_from_this and weak pointers in the handlers will become necessary.

Comment: Obviously I don't have any idea how complex your application is, and this does not address your actual issue, but I think your problem lies in `worker` holding an instance of `std::thread`. This is the cause of your current problem, and will also be a concern when you have many workers, especially if your workers have short lifetime : you will spawn many threads, which can be costly, especially if you have more threads than your hardware has cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `thread` object should be owned by the code managing the lifetime of the thread.

Currently, your `thread`'s lifetime is managed by your `worker` class, and your `worker` class's lifetime is managed by the thread of execution.

This is a pretty fundamental management loop.

The semantics of worker destruction are also exceedingly confusing.  You have shared pointers, and when the last shared pointer is destroyed the operation blocks on some thread somewhere finishing some unknown task.  Predicting what reference counting operations block becomes nearly impossible under this system.

---

One approach is to capture weak pointers to workers within workers.  Then the code in charge of managing the worker thread lifetime gets to pick when they all wrap up; when the shared pointer is gone.

---

Threads in general need to be managed by an exterior entity.

An approach that might be useful would be a thread pool with named task queues.  Each task queue is guaranteed to run in-order, so it acts like a thread, but there isn't a guarantee that the tasks in the queue will run on the same thread, nor is there a guarantee that a thread will idle waiting for new tasks in a queue.

You can either use something like a guid to name queues, or a less globally unique identifier generated on request (like a `new`'d pointer of some kind).  In the case of the second, the equivalent of your `.join()` call is disposing your thread queue id.

This does move you further away from using raw `boost` threading primitives; but in my experience the `std`-style primitives are a step up from using pthreads style threads, but are still far from what you actually want to use directly in client code.